# DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. "contract Ownable is Context "

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, contract-deployment, smart-contract-wallets

I´m trying to compile an smart contract created in cointool using REMIX, but it shows the following error and I didn't know how to solve it. Could you please help me?

This is  error message:

> 

DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
--> mm.sol:158:23:
|
158 | contract Ownable is Context {
| ^^^^^^^

> 

and this is the code:

```
  contract Ownable is Context {
      address private _owner;
      address private _previousOwner;
      uint256 private _lockTime;
      event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);
  
      /**
       * @dev Initializes the contract setting the deployer as the initial owner.
       */
      constructor () {
          address msgSender = _msgSender();
          _owner = msgSender;
          emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
      }
  
      /**
       * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
       */
      function owner() public view returns (address) {
          return _owner;
      }
  
      /**
       * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
       */
      modifier onlyOwner() {
          require(_owner == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
          _;
      }

      function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
          emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
          _owner = address(0);
      }
  

      function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
          require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
          emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
          _owner = newOwner;
      }
  
      function geUnlockTime() public view returns (uint256) {
          return _lockTime;
      }
  
      //Locks the contract for owner for the amount of time provided
      function lock(uint256 time) public virtual onlyOwner {
          _previousOwner = _owner;
          _owner = address(0);
          _lockTime = now + time;
          emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
      }
      
      //Unlocks the contract for owner when _lockTime is exceeds
      function unlock() public virtual {
          require(_previousOwner == msg.sender, "You don't have permission to unlock");
          require(now > _lockTime , "Contract is locked until 7 days");
          emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, _previousOwner);
          _owner = _previousOwner;
      }
  }
  
  // pragma solidity >=0.5.0;
  
  interface IUniswapV2Factory {
      event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint);
  
      function feeTo() external view returns (address);
      function feeToSetter() external view returns (address);
  
      function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair);
      function allPairs(uint) external view returns (address pair);
      function allPairsLength() external view returns (uint);
  
      function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);
  
      function setFeeTo(address) external;
      function setFeeToSetter(address) external;
  }
  
  
  // pragma solidity >=0.5.0;
  
  interface IUniswapV2Pair {
      event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
      event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
  
      function name() external pure returns (string memory);
      function symbol() external pure returns (string memory);
      function decimals() external pure returns (uint8);
      function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
      function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
      function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);
  
      function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
      function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
      function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
  
      function DOMAIN_SEPARATOR() external view returns (bytes32);
      function PERMIT_TYPEHASH() external pure returns (bytes32);
      function nonces(address owner) external view returns (uint);
  
      function permit(address owner, address spender, uint value, uint deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external;
  
      event Mint(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1);
      event Burn(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, address indexed to);
      event Swap(
          address indexed sender,
          uint amount0In,
          uint amount1In,
          uint amount0Out,
          uint amount1Out,
          address indexed to
      );
      event Sync(uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1);
  
      function MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY() external pure returns (uint);
      function factory() external view returns (address);
      function token0() external view returns (address);
      function token1() external view returns (address);
      function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast);
      function price0CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
      function price1CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
      function kLast() external view returns (uint);
  
      function mint(address to) external returns (uint liquidity);
      function burn(address to) external returns (uint amount0, uint amount1);
      function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external;
      function skim(address to) external;
      function sync() external;
  
      function initialize(address, address) external;
  }
  
  // pragma solidity >=0.6.2;
  
  interface IUniswapV2Router01 {
      function factory() external pure returns (address);
      function WETH() external pure returns (address);
  
      function addLiquidity(
          address tokenA,
          address tokenB,
          uint amountADesired,
          uint amountBDesired,
          uint amountAMin,
          uint amountBMin,
          address to,
          uint deadline
      ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity);
      function addLiquidityETH(
          address token,
          uint amountTokenDesired,
          uint amountTokenMin,
          uint amountETHMin,
          address to,
          uint deadline
      ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
      function removeLiquidity(
          address tokenA,
          address tokenB,
          uint liquidity,
          uint amountAMin,
          uint amountBMin,
          address to,
          uint deadline
      ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
      function removeLiquidityETH(
          address token,
          uint liquidity,
          uint amountTokenMin,
          uint amountETHMin,
          address to,
          uint deadline
      ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
      function removeLiquidityWithPermit(
          address tokenA,
          address tokenB,
          uint liquidity,
          uint amountAMin,
          uint amountBMin,
          address to,
          uint deadline,
          bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
      ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
      function removeLiquidityETHWithPermit(
          address token,
          uint liquidity,
          uint amountTokenMin,
          uint amountETHMin,
          address to,
          uint deadline,
          bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
      ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
      function swapExactTokensForTokens(
          uint amountIn,
          uint amountOutMin,
          address[] calldata path,
          address to,
          uint deadline
      ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
      function swapTokensForExactTokens(
          uint amountOut,
          uint amountInMax,
          address[] calldata path,
          address to,
          uint deadline
      ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
      function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
          external
          payable
          returns (uint[] memory amounts);
      function swapTokensForExactETH(uint amountOut, uint amountInMax, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
          external
          returns (uint[] memory amounts);
      function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
          external
          returns (uint[] memory amounts);
      function swapETHForExactTokens(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
          external
          payable
          returns (uint[] memory amounts);
  
      function quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB) external pure returns (uint amountB);
      function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountOut);
      function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountIn);
      function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
      function getAmountsIn(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
  }
  
  
  
  // pragma solidity >=0.6.2;
  
  interface IUniswapV2Router02 is IUniswapV2Router01 {
      function removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
          address token,
          uint liquidity,
          uint amountTokenMin,
          uint amountETHMin,
          address to,
          uint deadline
      ) external returns (uint amountETH);
      function removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
          address token,
          uint liquidity,
          uint amountTokenMin,
          uint amountETHMin,
          address to,
          uint deadline,
          bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
      ) external returns (uint amountETH);
  
      function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
          uint amountIn,
          uint amountOutMin,
          address[] calldata path,
          address to,
          uint deadline
      ) external;
      function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
          uint amountOutMin,
          address[] calldata path,
          address to,
          uint deadline
      ) external payable;
      function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
          uint amountIn,
          uint amountOutMin,
          address[] calldata path,
          address to,
          uint deadline
      ) external;
  }
  
  
  contract CoinTool is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
      using SafeMath for uint256;
      using Address for address;
  
      mapping (address => uint256) private _rOwned;
      mapping (address => uint256) private _tOwned;
      mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;
  
      mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;
  
      mapping (address => bool) private _isExcluded;
      address[] private _excluded;
     
      uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);
      uint256 private _tTotal = 1000000000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
      uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
      uint256 private _tFeeTotal;
  
      string private _name = "CoinTool";
      string private _symbol = "CoinTool";
      uint8 private _decimals = 9;
      
      uint256 public _taxFee = 5;
      uint256 private _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
      
      uint256 public _liquidityFee = 5;
      uint256 private _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
  
      IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uniswapV2Router;
      address public immutable uniswapV2Pair;
      
      bool inSwapAndLiquify;
      bool public swapAndLiquifyEnabled = true;
      
      uint256 public _maxTxAmount = 5000000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
      uint256 private numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity = 500000 * 10**6 * 10**9;

      address public routerAddress;
      
      event MinTokensBeforeSwapUpdated(uint256 minTokensBeforeSwap);
      event SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(bool enabled);
      event SwapAndLiquify(
          uint256 tokensSwapped,
          uint256 ethReceived,
          uint256 tokensIntoLiqudity
      );
      
      modifier lockTheSwap {
          inSwapAndLiquify = true;
          _;
          inSwapAndLiquify = false;
      }
      
      constructor () public {
          _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
          
          IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress);
           // Create a uniswap pair for this new token
          uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
              .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());
  
          // set the rest of the contract variables
          uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
          
          //exclude owner and this contract from fee
          _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
          _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
          
          emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
      }
  
      function name() public view returns (string memory) {
          return _name;
      }
  
      function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
          return _symbol;
      }
  
      function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
          return _decimals;
      }
  
      function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
          return _tTotal;
      }
  
      function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
          if (_isExcluded[account]) return _tOwned[account];
          return tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
      }
  
      function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
          _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
          return true;
      }
  
      function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view override returns (uint256) {
          return _allowances[owner][spender];
      }
  
      function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
          _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
          return true;
      }
  
      function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
          _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
          _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
          return true;
      }
  
      function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
          _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
          return true;
      }
  
      function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
          _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"));
          return true;
      }
  
      function isExcludedFromReward(address account) public view returns (bool) {
          return _isExcluded[account];
      }
  
      function totalFees() public view returns (uint256) {
          return _tFeeTotal;
      }
  
      function deliver(uint256 tAmount) public {
          address sender = _msgSender();
          require(!_isExcluded[sender], "Excluded addresses cannot call this function");
          (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
          _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
          _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rAmount);
          _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tAmount);
      }
  
      function reflectionFromToken(uint256 tAmount, bool deductTransferFee) public view returns(uint256) {
          require(tAmount <= _tTotal, "Amount must be less than supply");
          if (!deductTransferFee) {
              (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
              return rAmount;
          } else {
              (,uint256 rTransferAmount,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
              return rTransferAmount;
          }
      }
  
      function tokenFromReflection(uint256 rAmount) public view returns(uint256) {
          require(rAmount <= _rTotal, "Amount must be less than total reflections");
          uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
          return rAmount.div(currentRate);
      }
  
      function excludeFromReward(address account) public onlyOwner() {
          // require(account != 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D, 'We can not exclude Uniswap router.');
          require(!_isExcluded[account], "Account is already excluded");
          if(_rOwned[account] > 0) {
              _tOwned[account] = tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
          }
          _isExcluded[account] = true;
          _excluded.push(account);
      }
  
      function includeInReward(address account) external onlyOwner() {
          require(_isExcluded[account], "Account is already excluded");
          for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
              if (_excluded[i] == account) {
                  _excluded[i] = _excluded[_excluded.length - 1];
                  _tOwned[account] = 0;
                  _isExcluded[account] = false;
                  _excluded.pop();
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
          function _transferBothExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
          (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
          _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
          _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
          _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
          _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);        
          _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
          _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
          emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
      }
      
          function excludeFromFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
          _isExcludedFromFee[account] = true;
      }
      
      function includeInFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
          _isExcludedFromFee[account] = false;
      }
      
      function setTaxFeePercent(uint256 taxFee) external onlyOwner() {
          _taxFee = taxFee;
      }
      
      function setLiquidityFeePercent(uint256 liquidityFee) external onlyOwner() {
          _liquidityFee = liquidityFee;
      }
     
      function setMaxTxPercent(uint256 maxTxPercent) external onlyOwner() {
          _maxTxAmount = _tTotal.mul(maxTxPercent).div(
              10**2
          );
      }
  
      function setSwapAndLiquifyEnabled(bool _enabled) public onlyOwner {
          swapAndLiquifyEnabled = _enabled;
          emit SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(_enabled);
      }
      
       //to recieve ETH from uniswapV2Router when swaping
      receive() external payable {}
  
      function _reflectFee(uint256 rFee, uint256 tFee) private {
          _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rFee);
          _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tFee);
      }
  
      function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
          (uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getTValues(tAmount);
          (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, _getRate());
          return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity);
      }
  
      function _getTValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
          uint256 tFee = calculateTaxFee(tAmount);
          uint256 tLiquidity = calculateLiquidityFee(tAmount);
          uint256 tTransferAmount = tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tLiquidity);
          return (tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity);
      }
  
      function _getRValues(uint256 tAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 currentRate) private pure returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
          uint256 rAmount = tAmount.mul(currentRate);
          uint256 rFee = tFee.mul(currentRate);
          uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
          uint256 rTransferAmount = rAmount.sub(rFee).sub(rLiquidity);
          return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee);
      }
  
      function _getRate() private view returns(uint256) {
          (uint256 rSupply, uint256 tSupply) = _getCurrentSupply();
          return rSupply.div(tSupply);
      }
  
      function _getCurrentSupply() private view returns(uint256, uint256) {
          uint256 rSupply = _rTotal;
          uint256 tSupply = _tTotal;      
          for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
              if (_rOwned[_excluded[i]] > rSupply || _tOwned[_excluded[i]] > tSupply) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
              rSupply = rSupply.sub(_rOwned[_excluded[i]]);
              tSupply = tSupply.sub(_tOwned[_excluded[i]]);
          }
          if (rSupply < _rTotal.div(_tTotal)) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
          return (rSupply, tSupply);
      }
      
      function _takeLiquidity(uint256 tLiquidity) private {
          uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
          uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
          _rOwned[address(this)] = _rOwned[address(this)].add(rLiquidity);
          if(_isExcluded[address(this)])
              _tOwned[address(this)] = _tOwned[address(this)].add(tLiquidity);
      }
      
      function calculateTaxFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
          return _amount.mul(_taxFee).div(
              10**2
          );
      }
  
      function calculateLiquidityFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
          return _amount.mul(_liquidityFee).div(
              10**2
          );
      }
      
      function removeAllFee() private {
          if(_taxFee == 0 && _liquidityFee == 0) return;
          
          _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
          _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
          
          _taxFee = 0;
          _liquidityFee = 0;
      }
      
      function restoreAllFee() private {
          _taxFee = _previousTaxFee;
          _liquidityFee = _previousLiquidityFee;
      }
      
      function isExcludedFromFee(address account) public view returns(bool) {
          return _isExcludedFromFee[account];
      }
  
      function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
          require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
          require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");
  
          _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
          emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
      }
  
      function _transfer(
          address from,
          address to,
          uint256 amount
      ) private {
          require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
          require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
          require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
          if(from != owner() && to != owner())
              require(amount <= _maxTxAmount, "Transfer amount exceeds the maxTxAmount.");
  
          // is the token balance of this contract address over the min number of
          // tokens that we need to initiate a swap + liquidity lock?
          // also, don't get caught in a circular liquidity event.
          // also, don't swap & liquify if sender is uniswap pair.
          uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
          
          if(contractTokenBalance >= _maxTxAmount)
          {
              contractTokenBalance = _maxTxAmount;
          }
          
          bool overMinTokenBalance = contractTokenBalance >= numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
          if (
              overMinTokenBalance &&
              !inSwapAndLiquify &&
              from != uniswapV2Pair &&
              swapAndLiquifyEnabled
          ) {
              contractTokenBalance = numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
              //add liquidity
              swapAndLiquify(contractTokenBalance);
          }
          
          //indicates if fee should be deducted from transfer
          bool takeFee = true;
          
          //if any account belongs to _isExcludedFromFee account then remove the fee
          if(_isExcludedFromFee[from] || _isExcludedFromFee[to]){
              takeFee = false;
          }
          
          //transfer amount, it will take tax, burn, liquidity fee
          _tokenTransfer(from,to,amount,takeFee);
      }
  
      function swapAndLiquify(uint256 contractTokenBalance) private lockTheSwap {
          // split the contract balance into halves
          uint256 half = contractTokenBalance.div(2);
          uint256 otherHalf = contractTokenBalance.sub(half);
  
          // capture the contract's current ETH balance.
          // this is so that we can capture exactly the amount of ETH that the
          // swap creates, and not make the liquidity event include any ETH that
          // has been manually sent to the contract
          uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;
  
          // swap tokens for ETH
          swapTokensForEth(half); // <- this breaks the ETH -> HATE swap when swap+liquify is triggered
  
          // how much ETH did we just swap into?
          uint256 newBalance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBalance);
  
          // add liquidity to uniswap
          addLiquidity(otherHalf, newBalance);
          
          emit SwapAndLiquify(half, newBalance, otherHalf);
      }
  
      function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
          // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
          address[] memory path = new address[](2);
          path[0] = address(this);
          path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
  
          _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
  
          // make the swap
          uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
              tokenAmount,
              0, // accept any amount of ETH
              path,
              address(this),
              block.timestamp
          );
      }
  
      function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 ethAmount) private {
          // approve token transfer to cover all possible scenarios
          _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
  
          // add the liquidity
          uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
              address(this),
              tokenAmount,
              0, // slippage is unavoidable
              0, // slippage is unavoidable
              owner(),
              block.timestamp
          );
      }
  
      //this method is responsible for taking all fee, if takeFee is true
      function _tokenTransfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount,bool takeFee) private {
          if(!takeFee)
              removeAllFee();
          
          if (_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
              _transferFromExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
          } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
              _transferToExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
          } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
              _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
          } else if (_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
              _transferBothExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
          } else {
              _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
          }
          
          if(!takeFee)
              restoreAllFee();
      }
  
      function _transferStandard(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
          (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
          _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
          _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
          _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
          _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
          emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
      }
  
      function _transferToExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
          (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
          _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
          _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
          _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);           
          _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
          _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
          emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
      }
```

I'll appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Please attach the full code, contract ```Context``` is missing. There might be an issue with the way you're attaching it.

Comment: hello, @MiroslavNedelchev thanks for answering, here is the following

Comment: Are you sure? Contract ```Context``` is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to top of your contract:

```
contract Context {
// Empty internal constructor, to prevent people from mistakenly deploying
// an instance of this contract, which should be used via inheritance.
constructor() internal {}

function _msgSender() internal view returns (address payable) {
    return msg.sender;
}

function _msgData() internal view returns (bytes memory) {
    this; // silence state mutability warning without generating bytecode - see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691
    return msg.data;
} }
```